# Как генерировать элементы управления?

Tags: vba, excel

Уважаемые программисты на VBA excel, Vba!

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, как генерировать элементы управления (такие как: TextBox, Label, CommandButton и др.) при нажатии на Button. А конкретнее при выборе значения в ComboBox, состоящих из трех значений, в каждом из которых записано создание новой группы, где несколько textbox и один button в произвольном порядке.

Помогите начинающему. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В VBA есть возможность спрятать или не показать элемент? Если есть - воспользуйся им. Присвой команду событию нажатия button с проверкой необходимых тебе условий. Если под excel вы имеете в виду распознавание формул, думаю, что вряд ли. Но таблица для выведения данных должна быть.

Comment: А если данных групп должно быть много? Но при этом показывать все может быть не обязательно (если пользователь все не прокликает).

Comment: А если мне, например, нужен комбобокс с выбором чисел от одного до 10. В зависимости от того, какое число выберет пользователь, столько текстбоксов нужно добавить на форму. Как описать процесс самого создания этих элементов?

Comment: Создание как раз не интересно - добавил заранее и попрятал их всех.

Answer (score 0):

Натыкать скрытых элементов и делать их видимыми по мере необходимости. Элементы вполне можно создавать динамически:

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=100, Height:=30
    Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", Left:=10, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=20
    Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=10, Top:=80, Width:=100, Height:=20
```

Как привязать к этим элементам обработчики событий, читаем [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476481/detecting-event-on-comboboxes-added-at-runtime-on-excel).